# PostgreSQL ,Postgis and Pgrouting compatible versions

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, postgis, pgrouting

I am trying to work with PostgreSql 9.3, Postgis 2.1.3 and Pgrouting 2.0.0 versions in Ubuntu (VPS). I have installed PostgreSql 9.3,but when i run  `CREATE EXTENSION postgis  SCHEMA public  VERSION "2.0.0";` in PgAdmin3 i get ERROR:  could not stat file "/usr/share/postgresql/9.3/extension/postgis--2.1.3.sql": No such file or directory and same error with Pgrouting 2.0.0.Are these versions compatibles running in that system?,in localhost work fine.

Comment: Yes, this should work. What repository did you install from or did you compile from source?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am new in ubuntu and i don't know exactly how to install postgis and the extensions using repositories. Should i edit the pg_config file in postgresql?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.3 postgresql-9.3-postgis-2.1 postgresql-9.3-postgis-scripts postgresql-contrib-9.3 postgresql-client-common postgresql-common postgresql-server-dev-9.3 postgresql-client-9.3
```

This should install everything and start the server. Read the following man pages. to create a user and a database.

```
man createuser
man createdb
```

and this will install postgis into database 'mydatabase' for user 'user':

```
psql -U user mydatabase -c "create extension postgis"
```